# Large Delay with ECS service discovery DNS updates

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I'm trying to find out why the AWS DNS Servers (10.0.0.2 and 169.254.169.253) takes ages to return the correct IP address for my ECS tasks.

The setup I currently have is as follows:

- dev.private is the Route53 hosted zone
- An ECS service (that registers under deepstream.dev.private) using a TTL 0 and an A type dns entry
- An nginx service that does SSL termination and forwards requests to the ECS service

When first creating the EC2 instance and installing nginx everything works with a resolver pointing to 10.0.0.2

However, when killing the ECS task:

- it is removed from route53 (expected)
- new task entry is entered into route53 with the new IP (expected)
- the new entry does NOT show up in nginx (it returns (3: Host not found))
- the new entry does NOT show up when using dig (dig @10.0.0.2 deepstream.dev.private)

```
dig @10.0.0.2 deepstream.dev.private

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.amzn2.0.2 <<>> @10.0.0.2 deepstream.dev.private
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 10878
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;deepstream.dev.private.                IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.2#53(10.0.0.2)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 14 03:33:39 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 51
```

That shows that there is no answer

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.amzn2.0.2 <<>> @10.0.0.2 deepstream.dev.private
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15576
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;deepstream.dev.private.                IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
deepstream.dev.private. 0       IN      A       10.0.2.214

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 10.0.0.2#53(10.0.0.2)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 14 03:35:00 UTC 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 56
```

So to summarise test scenario:

- Dig returns IP and all is well
- Immediately after killing ECS task the Route53 entry is removed
- Less than 10seconds later (time required to restart docker on ECS) new Route 53 entry is added with IP
- 5 minutes later the new entry is returned via dig

Ran this multiple times and it seems to constantly be five minutes, which feels like a cache somewhere.

It can't be expected to take 5 minutes for a new ECS instance to be referenced after crashing or deployments, that would be unacceptable downtime.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to [negative DNS caching](https://github.com/aws/aws-app-mesh-roadmap/issues/221) in the Cloud Map namespaces that ECS uses to provide service discovery. Prior to 09/14/2020, the default (and fixed) negative caching TTL (in other words, the TTL of the namespace's SOA record) was 300 seconds (your 5 minute value) for namespaces with VPC resolution only, and 900 seconds for namespaces with public DNS resolution.

According to the linked GitHub issue, the defaults for newly created namespaces are now 15 seconds and 60 seconds, respectively.

I had come across this issue as well and had a hard time tracking down the cause, as this only happens when the number of available tasks drops all the way to 0, thus causing to the cached NXDOMAIN response.

At least as of the time of this writing, it's not possible to manually modify this value (though this is in progress, according to the GitHub issue), so the only solution is to recreate the namespace to obtain the new lower default value.